# Faasd - can't pull image from private registry

Tags: docker, serverless, containerd, faas, openfaas

I have an application that uses OpenFaaS.

In particular, I'm using ***faasd*** because the function will run on devices with poor processing capacity.
I have a private registry on which an image of an 'X' function is present.
I want to pull this image from faasd to deploy and execute it, but I'm facing a problem: it seems like I'm not authenticated when I try to perform the action, but I pass correctly the registryAuth token.

Here there is an example of what I'm doing (following this https://ericstoekl.github.io/faas/operations/managing-images/#deploy-functions-with-private-registries-credentials)

POST

```
<ip_address>:8080/system/functions
```

Headers:

```
{
"Authorization": "mytoken"
}
```

Body:

```
{
    "service": "functionName",
    "image": "<registry_ip_address>/functions/functionName:<version>",
    "envProcess": "/.../myprocess",
    "registryAuth": <base64 token obtained from 'user:password'>,
    "secrets": [
        "mysecret"
    ]
}
```

I confirm that parameters are all correct and I receive this error:

***"unable to pull image <registry_ip_address>/functions/functionName:: cannot pull: failed to resolve reference "<registry_ip_address>/functions/functionName:": no scope specified for token auth challenge"***

The registry is working well because if I try to download the image in a classic way with docker, I'm able to pull the image.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 7):

For faasd you have to make a credential file.

Your normal ~/.docker/config.json needs to be copied to `/var/lib/faasd/.docker/config.json`.

[https://github.com/openfaas/faasd#a-note-on-private-repos--registries](https://github.com/openfaas/faasd/tree/294ef0f17f02e04768adfbd9a80acba5eded2253#a-note-on-private-repos--registries)

> **A note on private repos / registries**
>
> To use private image repos, `~/.docker/config.json` needs to be copied to `/var/lib/faasd/.docker/config.json.`
>
> If you'd like to set up your own private registry, see [this tutorial](https://blog.alexellis.io/get-a-tls-enabled-docker-registry-in-5-minutes/).
>
> Beware that running `docker login` on MacOS and Windows may create an empty file with your credentials stored in the system helper.
>
> Alternatively, use you can use the `registry-login` command from the OpenFaaS Cloud bootstrap tool (ofc-bootstrap):
>
> ```
> curl -sLSf https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openfaas-incubator/ofc-bootstrap/master/get.sh | sudo sh
>
> ofc-bootstrap registry-login --username <your-registry-username> --password-stdin
> # (then enter your password and hit return)
> ```
>
> The file will be created in `./credentials/`

Comment: Thank you! Thant helped me a lot :-) Looks like your provided link does not contain the information anymore.

Comment: @Klaus I added the content from the original document so that it will stay on stack into the future. Now if I can just figure this out too...